# Open nerdtree automatically when start vim on a folder and don't show two tree viewers

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I would like to open NERDtree automatically but only when passing a folder argument in command line, and that it would not open two tree viewers, only NERDtree. For example, if I am on folder 'rootFolder', which has a 'childFolder' and I run:

```
nvim childFolder
```

I would like it to open vim like if I had done:

```
cd childFolder
nvim
:NERDtree
```

And if I open a file or empty I would like it to not show nerdtree. That way if I just work on a single file like:

```
nvim
```

or

```
nvim test.js
```

or

```
nvim reminder.txt
```

I don't need to see NERDtree, because I don't need it, it's just a test script or a notes file I am leaving myself.

Comment: is vim explorer good enough for you?

Comment: You could have a custom bash command to do this instead of trying to reach this from vim. e.g. function that calls `nvim +cd $1 | NERDtree`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround, add these two lines in .vimrc:

```
let g:NERDTreeHijackNetrw = 1
au VimEnter NERD_tree_1 enew | execute 'NERDTree '.argv()[0]
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, you don't need to set `NERDTreeHijackNetrw` to 1—it's set by default. And why do you say it's a "workaround", doesn't it solve part of your problem still?

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how NERDTree behaves if `'NERDTreeHijackNetrw'` is set to 1 (which it is by default.)

Comment: When 'NERDTreeHijackNetrw' is set to 1 it switches but it doesn't keep it open when selecting a file, that's what I want, that's what that chain of commands I used as an example would do. I just want to know if there is a way to open exactly how I described. I know it might sound foolish, or unecessary, but that's basically what any other editor does (i.e sublime).

Answer (score 0):

The previously selected answer didn't work for me, but from NERDTRee's docs, they have [a few different solutions depending on your desired behaviour](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree#how-do-i-open-nerdtree-automatically-when-vim-starts). I think you're looking for the last snippet from the first section:

```
" Start NERDTree when Vim starts with a directory argument.
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists('s:std_in') |
    \ execute 'NERDTree' argv()[0] | wincmd p | enew | execute 'cd '.argv()[0] | endif
```